# Limit of a the function $f(x,y)=x \log(y-x)$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :y>x\}$ and $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)=x \log(y-x)$.
Does the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} f(x,y)$ exist?

I consider $E=\{(-t,t) : t>0\}$ so $f\vert_{E}=-t\log(2t) \to 0 $ for $t \to 0$. So the limit is null?

Comment: There are many other paths along which we could approach $(0,0)$.

Comment: To expand on the comment above: if you think the limit is 0, you need to show this in general, not by exhibiting a single path along which the function approaches zero. For example, there are are functions for which the limit does not exist exactly because approaching the limit point from different directions yields different apparent limits.

Comment: I don't think the initial limit is correct but try another path to the point, if they result in different values then it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Approach $(0,0)$ along a path with $x$ positive and $y=x+e^{-1/x}$.